# Android TV emulator locale

Tags: android-emulator, locale

I want to change language setting in the Android TV emulator in order to for me to do testing. But seems that, there is only English language available in the emulator. Is it Google still not implement yet other locale in the Android TV emulator? Because i check in other emulators, i mean phone or any else, there are variety of languages can be choose.

Comment: you tried this, right? `Open menu=>Setting=>Language& Keyboard=>Select Locale=>set any locale from this`?

Comment: yes. but in tv emulator, language and keyboard is separated icon. even in keyboard, the only only option available is keyboard type, which is the leanback keyboard.